# Options for OAUTH2 in ASP.NET Web API 2 hosted on windows Azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth

Good evening, I want to create a RESTful API with ASP.NET Web API 2 and host it in Windows Azure. For this API I will need to have registered users and I want them to register via Facebook or Twitter. The question is, which would be the easiest way to have OAUTH2 integrated with the API in Azure? I saw that it has the ASP.NET Identity integrated with it but I don't know how nicely it works in azure, are there any other options?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to leverage Access Control Services (ACS) and OAuth2.  This article has a great description of how to set it up: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/147914/protecting-your-aspnet-web-api-using-oauth2-and-the-windows-azure-access-control-service/

Comment: Thanks a lot, will look in to that. One more question, do you know if azure charges anything for that service? if so, how much is it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Azure ACS is free. See "Azure AD Access Control" on this page: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/